# Mongo command to fech records based on the field present inside json object

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, robo3t

I'm using MongoDB and I have a signed data collection and the record is of below format:

```
{
 "_id" : "50000235-01",
 "requiredDocs" : {
     "docSigned": "Y",
     "responseCode" : "0"
   }
}
```

Now I want to fetch all the records where I have:

```
"docSigned": "N"
```

I'm using robo3t tool to connect to MongoDB and fetching the record. Can someone help with the mongo MongoDB in fetching this type?

```
db.getCollection('signeddata').find({}).sort({$natural:-1})
```

Can someone help with the condition given with in `find({})`

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved.I've used below command and it worked.

```
db.getCollection('signeddata').find({'requiredDocs.docSigned':'N'}).sort({$natural:-1})
```